# tcpdump shows packets but application shows packets are bursty

Tags: linux, sockets, c++11, tcp, poco-libraries

I'm working on a system in which I cannot divulge too much information but I figure I can describe the issue to get some breadcrumbs of where the most likely culprit is.

I have an application running on an embedded Linux system that has a TCP server listening on an IP and port. It is waiting for an external client from outside the system to connect to it in which it will accept the connection to respond to the client.

The client is expected to send messages at an approximate rate of 120 ms or 8 messages per second. When the client connects, tcpdump verifies that the interface is receiving the messages at ~120ms intervals from the client but the server application is seeing it as bursts.

Bursts as in it receives X number of messages and then Y number of seconds of dead silence pass and the process repeats.

The application only expects for one client to connect and the app is single threaded. Does anyone have an idea as to why TCP in Linux may exhibit this behavior? Any ideas of where to look between the application and the Linux sockets?

NOTE 1:
Also another point to make, I'm making use of the POCO library for my application. I am using StreamSocket and ServerSocket wrappers. 
https://pocoproject.org/

NOTE 2: 
I should also note that this is not always the case. Sometimes, my application receives the packets at the expected ~120ms interval. So it does work properly but this bug comes up every once in a while.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a result of Nagle's algorithm. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle's_algorithm

That is: sender's data are accumulated together and later send out together to reduce the overhead caused by sending individual packet. Try set socket option TCP_NODELAY at client side and see if it works.

To determine real cause, packet capture of both server/client would be helpful.

Comment: So I do, but what would you want to look for? Also the the size of each message being sent is 16 bytes, the response message is less than that.

Comment: I would first verify if the client sends a packet every 120ms and whether the server receives every individual packet or one big chunk packet instead.

Comment: Well tcpdump has a timestamp associated with each packet received from the client. It shows the ~120 ms interval - which appears to be the first thing you stated to verify. This would almost imply its not the Nagle's algorithm as the culprit. Would you draw the same conclusion then?

Comment: Agree. Now seems to me the data is simply buffered at application layer. To determine, print out number of bytes received at your server side. If it's more than 16 bytes and not Nagle's related, then it's simply a normal TCP application layer behavior.